# Our Exercise code is outputting an unexpected -1 and we don't know why

Tags: c

So we are working on an exercise for Uni and we can't figure out why this code outputs the second value as -1
We believe that it is due to the 16-bit limit but don't understand exactly why and can't find any sources on this issue since we don't know what it actually is. I'm sorry if this seems really stupid, please help D:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  int16_t y = 1024, z = 65; // auch "short" als Datentyp verwendbar

  y = y * z;
  printf("1. Ausgabe: %d\n", y);
  printf("2. Ausgabe: %d\n", y / 3 * 3 - 3 * y / 3);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

we expected the result to be 0 for  2. Ausgabe but it outputs  -1

Comment: Suggestion: break it up into smaller parts by introducing extra variables, then examine these variables individually.

Comment: Hint: Use a debugger or try printing intermediate values. For example `y`, `y / 3`, `y / 3 * 3` etc in hex and convert them to 16 bit binary. Understand rounding in `C`. For example what is the output of `i / 3 * 3` for `i = 0, 1, 2, .... 15`. `signed` overflow is undefined behavior in C.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division)

Comment: You are also using the wrong format specifiers for `int16_t`. Strictly speaking it should be `"%"PRIi16` from inttypes.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the range for a int16_t is −32,768 ... 32,767

**y * z = 1024*65 = 66560** but hence will be stored as **66560 % 2^16 = 1024**
so you still have **y = 1024** and your statement **y = y * z** is useless

**y / 3 * 3 = (y / 3) * 3  = 341 * 3 = 1023 != y** because of rounding

**3 * y / 3 = (3 * y) / 3 = y** because there is no rounding

when you substract you get -1

the problem is you're overflowing your variable and doing integer divisions

use floats instead of int16_t

Comment: You missed the statement `y = y * z`.

Comment: @Wheatley You shouldn't rely on overflowing signed integers. It's undefined behaviour. The result can be anything.

Comment: @JUSHJUSH Assuming `int` is 32 bits, then `y * z` never overflows a signed integer and there is no UB anywhere. Converting a large signed integer to a smaller one is implementation-defined, not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`int16_t` has the range `[−32768, +32767]` - you are overflowing that range immediately with the first multiplication.

What does the first printf print out? That should have been an indication. You also mention it in your question.

Google `int16_t range` and it will show you the range above. Try using an int32_t and see what difference that makes.

Comment: so does that mean that because of the range limit the calculation simplifies to 32767 + (-32768)= -1

Comment: "you are overflowing that range immediately" Not in case `int` is 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Given `y = y * z;` where all operands are type `int16_t` and the values are 1024 * 65 = 66560, 
then there are two possibilities:

- If your system is 8 or 16 bit, you will have 16 bit `int` type. There will be no type promotion of the operands since they are already 16 bits and you get a signed integer overflow, invoking undefined behavior. Since 16 bit signed integers can only store values up to 32767.
- If your system is 32 bit, then both `y` and `z` are implicitly promoted (see [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)) to type `int` which is then 32 bits. The result of the multiplication is of type `int`. The value 66560 will fit just fine.

  You then convert this 32 bit `int` to `int16_t` upon assignment. The value will no longer fit - what will happen is an implementation-defined conversion from signed 32 to signed 16. (In theory your system may raise a signal here.)

  In practice most systems will simply take the 66560 = 10400h and cut off the MS bytes, leaving you with 1024 = 400h.

In either case, the equation `y = y * z;` is highly questionable given the size of the input values! This is to be regarded as a bug. You should use `uint16_t` or `int32_t` instead.

---

As for `y / 3 * 3 - 3 * y / 3`, it will be `1024 / 3 * 3 - 3 * 1024 / 3`. All operands are integers and the operator associativity of multiplicative operators `*` and `/` is left-to-right.

So you get `341 * 3 - 3072 / 3` -> `1023 - 1024` = `-1`.

---

As a side-note, you are using the wrong `printf` conversion specifier. The most correct one for `int16_t` is this:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

printf("1. Ausgabe: %"PRIi16 "\n", y);
```